# Most efficient method of generating a random number with a fixed number of bits set

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, random, bit-manipulation

I need to generate a random number, but it needs to be selected from the set of binary numbers with equal numbers of set bits. E.g. choose a random byte value with exactly 2 bits set...

```
00000000 - no
00000001 - no
00000010 - no
00000011 - YES
00000100 - no
00000101 - YES
00000110 - YES
...

=> Set of possible numbers 3, 5, 6...
```

Note that this is a simplified set of numbers. Think more along the lines of 'Choose a random 64-bit number with exactly 40 bits set'. Each number from the set must be equally likely to arise.

Comment: Choose `N` random positions for the set bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a random selection from the set of all bit positions, then set those bits.

Example in Python:

```
def random_bits(word_size, bit_count):
    number = 0
    for bit in random.sample(range(word_size), bit_count):
        number |= 1 << bit
    return number
```

Results of running the above 10 times:

```
0xb1f69da5cb867efbL
0xfceff3c3e16ea92dL
0xecaea89655befe77L
0xbf7d57a9b62f338bL
0x8cd1fee76f2c69f7L
0x8563bfc6d9df32dfL
0xdf0cdaebf0177e5fL
0xf7ab75fe3e2d11c7L
0x97f9f1cbb1f9e2f8L
0x7f7f075de5b73362L
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't select the same one twice.

Comment: The set will be nCr sized.

C(64,40) = 64! / ( 40! (64 - 40)! ) = 

250649105469666120 entries. Too big to fit in memory, might need to compress in some sort.

Comment: you need to account for the fact that you might select the same position twice

Comment: @Uday, I said "bit positions" - there are only 64 of those. I hope the code sample I added makes it clearer.

Comment: @frankc, forgive me if I wasn't clear. By "random selection" I meant choosing from a set where the members of the set are already unique.

Comment: If you use Mersenne Twister as random number generator then the random value returned will be uniform in the range (0,2^k-1).

Comment: global_bits = [2**bit for bit in range(64)]; def r(k): return sum(random.sample(global_bits, k))

Comment: @rici, same principle different implementation. You could submit that as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom, it's exactly the same, just does a precomputation for efficiency, fwiw. Wouldn't want to steal your glory :)

Answer (score 6):

I have found an elegant solution: random-dichotomy.

Idea is that on average:

- *and* with a random number is dividing by 2 the number of set bits,
- *or* is adding 50% of set bits.

C code to compile with gcc (to have __builtin_popcountll):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/// Return a random number, with nb_bits bits set out of the width LSB
uint64_t random_bits(uint8_t width, uint8_t nb_bits)
{
    assert(nb_bits <= width);
    assert(width <= 64);
    uint64_t x_min = 0;
    uint64_t x_max = width == 64 ? (uint64_t)-1 : (1UL<<width)-1;
    int n = 0;

    while (n != nb_bits)
    {
        // generate a random value of at least width bits
        uint64_t x = random();
        if (width > 31)
            x ^= random() << 31;
        if (width > 62)
            x ^= random() << 33;

        x = x_min | (x & x_max); // x_min is a subset of x, which is a subset of x_max
        n = __builtin_popcountll(x);
        printf("x_min = 0x%016lX, %d bits\n", x_min, __builtin_popcountll(x_min));
        printf("x_max = 0x%016lX, %d bits\n", x_max, __builtin_popcountll(x_max));
        printf("x     = 0x%016lX, %d bits\n\n", x, n);
        if (n > nb_bits)
            x_max = x;
        else
            x_min = x;
    }

    return x_min;
}
```

In general less than 10 loops are needed to reach the requested number of bits (and with luck it can take 2 or 3 loops). Corner cases (nb_bits=0,1,width-1,width) are working even if a special case would be faster.

Example of result:

```
x_min = 0x0000000000000000, 0 bits
x_max = 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 61 bits
x     = 0x1492717D79B2F570, 33 bits

x_min = 0x0000000000000000, 0 bits
x_max = 0x1492717D79B2F570, 33 bits
x     = 0x1000202C70305120, 14 bits

x_min = 0x0000000000000000, 0 bits
x_max = 0x1000202C70305120, 14 bits
x     = 0x0000200C10200120, 7 bits

x_min = 0x0000200C10200120, 7 bits
x_max = 0x1000202C70305120, 14 bits
x     = 0x1000200C70200120, 10 bits

x_min = 0x1000200C70200120, 10 bits
x_max = 0x1000202C70305120, 14 bits
x     = 0x1000200C70201120, 11 bits

x_min = 0x1000200C70201120, 11 bits
x_max = 0x1000202C70305120, 14 bits
x     = 0x1000200C70301120, 12 bits

width = 61, nb_bits = 12, x = 0x1000200C70301120
```

Of course, you need a good prng. Otherwise you can face an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

Say the number of bits to set is b and the word size is w.  I would create a vector v of of length w with the first b values set to 1 and the rest set to 0.  Then just shuffle v.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it'd be reasonable to write a 'bitwise shuffle' that shuffles the actual bits.

Comment: it should be possible.  The well-known best shuffle is called fisher-yates. It just involves swapping positions cleverly so I don't see why it couldn't be done with bitwise operations

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option which is very simple and reasonably fast in practice.

```
choose a bit at random
if it is already set
    do nothing
else
    set it
    increment count
end if
```

Repeat until count equals the number of bits you want set.

This will only be slow when the number of bits you want set (call it `k`) is more than half the word length (call it `N`).  In that case, use the algorithm to set `N` - `k` bits instead and then flip all the bits in the result.

I bet the expected running time here is pretty good, although I am too lazy/stupid to compute it precisely right now.  But I can bound it as less than 2*`k`...  The expected number of flips of a coin to get "heads" is two, and each iteration here has a better than 1/2 chance of succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the convenience of Python's `random.sample`, you might do this in C using the classic sequential sampling algorithm:

```
unsigned long k_bit_helper(int n, int k, unsigned long bit, unsigned long accum) {
  if !(n && k)
    return accum;
  if (k > rand() % n)
    return k_bit_helper(n - 1, k - 1, bit + bit, accum + bit);
  else
    return k_bit_helper(n - 1, k, bit + bit, accum);
}

unsigned long random_k_bits(int k) {
  return k_bit_helper(64, k, 1, 0);
}
```

The cost of the above will be dominated by the cost of generating the random numbers (true in the other solutions, also). You can optimize this a bit if you have a good prng by batching: for example, since you know that the random numbers will be in steadily decreasing ranges, you could get the random numbers for `n` through `n-3` by getting a random number in the range `0..(n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3))` and then extracting the individual random numbers:

```
r = randint(0, n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3) - 1);
rn  = r % n; r /= n
rn1 = r % (n - 1); r /= (n - 1);
rn2 = r % (n - 2); r /= (n - 2);
rn3 = r % (n - 3); r /= (n - 3);
```

The maximum value of `n` is presumably `64` or 2<sup>6</sup>, so the maximum value of the product above is certainly less than 2<sup>24</sup>. Indeed, if you used a 64-bit prng, you could extract as many as 10 random numbers out of it. However, don't do this unless you know the prng you use produces independently random bits.

Comment: That tip about slicing up long random numbers into smaller ranges is alone worth remembering.

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion based on enumeration: choose a random number i between 1 and n choose k, and generate the i-th combination. For example, for n = 6, k = 3 the 20 combinations are:

```
000111
001011
010011
100011
001101
010101
100101
011001
101001
110001
001110
010110
100110
011010
101010
110010
011100
101100
110100
111000
```

Let's say we randomly choose combination number 7. We first check whether it has a 1 in the last position: it has, because the first 10 (5 choose 2) combinations have. We then recursively check the remaining positions. Here is some C++ code:

```
word ithCombination(int n, int k, word i) {
    // i is zero-based
    word x = 0;
    word b = 1;
    while (k) {
        word c = binCoeff[n - 1][k - 1];
        if (i < c) {
            x |= b;
            --k;
        } else {
            i -= c;
        }
        --n;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return x;
}
word randomKBits(int k) {
    word i = randomRange(0, binCoeff[BITS_PER_WORD][k] - 1);
    return ithCombination(BITS_PER_WORD, k, i);
}
```

To be fast, we use precalculated binomial coefficients in `binCoeff`. The function `randomRange` returns a random integer between the two bounds (inclusively).

I did some timings ([source](https://github.com/falk-hueffner/randkbits)). With the C++11 default random number generator, most time is spent in generating random numbers. Then this solution is fastest, since it uses the absolute minimum number of random bits possible. If I use a fast random number generator, then the solution by mic006 is fastest. If `k` is known to be very small, it's best to just randomly set bits until `k` are set.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an algorithm suggestion, but just found a really neat solution in JavaScript to get random bits directly from Math.random output bits using ArrayBuffer.

```js
//Swap var out with const and let for maximum performance! I like to use var because of prototyping ease
var randomBitList = function(n){
    var floats = Math.ceil(n/64)+1;
    var buff = new ArrayBuffer(floats*8);
    var floatView = new Float64Array(buff);
    var int8View = new Uint8Array(buff);
    var intView = new Int32Array(buff);
    for(var i = 0; i < (floats-1)*2; i++){
        floatView[floats-1] = Math.random();
        int8View[(floats-1)*8] = int8View[(floats-1)*8+4];
        intView[i] = intView[(floats-1)*2];
    }
    this.get = function(idx){
        var i = idx>>5;//divide by 32
        var j = idx%32;
        return (intView[i]>>j)&1;
        //return Math.random()>0.5?0:1;
    };
    this.getBitList = function(){
        var arr = [];
        for(var idx = 0; idx < n; idx++){
            var i = idx>>5;//divide by 32
            var j = idx%32;
            arr[idx] = (intView[i]>>j)&1;
        }
        return arr;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simplest Snippet

The simplest working snippet is as follows. `onlyNBitsSetRNG64` takes a random 64-bit number, `rng`, and yields a random 64-bit number perfectly equidistributed with exactly `n` bits set. (Max of 10 bits set. Use the fast streaming function below to uncap this limit.)

```c
uint64_t onlyNBitsSetRNG64(uint64_t rng, unsigned n) {
    uint64_t res = 1;
    while(1) {
        res = (res >> (rng & 63)) | (res << (64 - (rng & 63)));
        rng >>= 6;
        if ( ! (n -= 1)) return res;
        res |= res + 1;
    }
}
```

If you only want to generate a 32-bit random number, then use `onlyNBitsSetRNG32` below, which has a max of 12 bits set.

```c
uint32_t onlyNBitsSetRNG32(uint64_t rng, unsigned n) {
    uint32_t res = 1;
    while(1) {
        res = (res >> (rng & 31)) | (res << (32 - (rng & 31)));
        rng >>= 5;
        if ( ! (n -= 1)) return res;
        res |= res + 1;
    }
}
```

### GB/s of speed

If you want gigabytes per second of fixed-set-bit integers in C, then use GCC with the following code, which leverages GCC's autovertorization logic and auto-detects supported CPU features (AVX2 and AVX512) at runtime, choosing the fastest path.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define RAND_INTN_NBIT(T, NAME, N) \
    T NAME { assert(((void)"N bits too big",N<=sizeof(rng)*8)); \
        unsigned i = N ; \
        for (T res = 1; 1; res|=res+1) { \
            const int SZT = sizeof(T), MSK = SZT*8 - 1; \
            res = (res>>(rng&MSK)) | (res<<(MSK+1 - (rng&MSK))); \
            rng >>= 3+(SZT>1)+(SZT>2)+(SZT>4)+(SZT>8)+(SZT>16); \
            if ( ! (i -= 1)) return res; \
        } return ((void)"Note: unreachable", 0); }

#define _RINB_VECSET1(N,vec) for(j=0;j<N;j++) vec[j] = 1;
#define _RINB_VECRD(N,vec) for(j=0;j<N;j++)memcpy(vec+j,rand+j,SZT); rand+=N;
#define _RINB_VECROL(N,v,S) for(j=0;j<N;j++)v[j]=(v[j]>>(S[j]&M1))|(v[j]<<(M-(S[j]&M1)));
#define _RINB_VECSHR(N,vec) for(j=0;j<N;j++) vec[j] >>= shft;
#define _RINB_VECAOR(N,vec) for(j=0;j<N;j++) vec[j] |= vec[j] + 1;
#define _RINB_VECWR(N,to,O,from) for(j=0;j<N;j++) to[O*N+j+leT] = from[j];
#define _RINB_SMB(N,V,T) \
    uint8_t SZT=(uint8_t)sizeof(T), M=(uint8_t)SZT*8, M1=M-1;\
    T * rand=(T*)rng, * e=(T*)&out[len]; size_t leT = -(size_t)len;\
    for(int k,i,j,shft=3+(SZT>1)+(SZT>2)+(SZT>4)+(SZT>8)+(SZT>16); leT; leT+=4*V){\
        T a[V],b[V],c[V],d[V]; \
        _RINB_VECSET1(V,a) _RINB_VECSET1(V,b) _RINB_VECSET1(V,c) _RINB_VECSET1(V,d) \
        int x=N; do { T aR[V],bR[V],cR[V],dR[V]; \
        _RINB_VECRD(V,aR)_RINB_VECRD(V,bR)_RINB_VECRD(V,cR)_RINB_VECRD(V,dR)\
        int l=M/shft; do { \
            _RINB_VECROL(V,a,aR)_RINB_VECROL(V,b,bR)_RINB_VECROL(V,c,cR)_RINB_VECROL(V,d,dR)\
            _RINB_VECSHR(V,aR) _RINB_VECSHR(V,bR) _RINB_VECSHR(V,cR) _RINB_VECSHR(V,dR) \
            if (!(x -= 1)) break; \
            else { _RINB_VECAOR(V,a) _RINB_VECAOR(V,b) _RINB_VECAOR(V,c) _RINB_VECAOR(V,d) }\
        } while (l -= 1); } while(x); \
        _RINB_VECWR(V,e,0,a)_RINB_VECWR(V,e,1,b)_RINB_VECWR(V,e,2,c)_RINB_VECWR(V,e,3,d)\
    }

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 202311L || defined(__GNUC__)
    #define _RINTNBIT_SMDEBN(O,N,V) static void O{_RINB_SMB(N,V,typeof(*out))}
#elif defined(__cplusplus)
    #define _RINTNBIT_SMDEBN(O,N,V) static void O{_RINB_SMB(N,V,decltype(*out))}
#else
    #define _RINTNBIT_SMDEBN(O,N,V) static void O {\
        if(sizeof(*out)==8){ _RINB_SMB(N,V,uint64_t) } \
        else if(sizeof(*out)==4){ _RINB_SMB(N,V,uint32_t) } \
        else if(sizeof(*out)==2){ _RINB_SMB(N,V,uint16_t) } \
        else if(sizeof(*out)==1){ _RINB_SMB(N,V,uint8_t) } \
        else assert(((void)"needed type size not found", 0));}
#endif

#define _RINTNBIT_SMIMPL(T,O,A,N,V) _RINTNBIT_SMDEBN(T DEB##O A,N,V) T static void O A{\
    if ((len&63) == 0) DEB ## O (out,len,rng); \
    else assert(((void)"length must be multiple 64 entries long", (len&63)==0)); }

#if defined(__x86_64__) && defined(__GNUC__)
    #ifdef __clang__
        #define _RINTNBCA(x,N) __attribute__((noinline,target(x)))
        #define _RINTNSIZE(N) __attribute__((noinline,minsize)) static void N
    #else
        #define _RINTNBCA(x,N) __attribute__((noinline,optimize("O3,"\
            "tree-vectorize,unroll-loops"),target(x",prefer-vector-width="#N)))
        #define _RINTNSIZE(N) __attribute__((noinline,optimize("Os"))) static void N
    #endif
    #define _RAND_INTNBIT_VECIMPL(O, A, N) \
        _RINTNBIT_SMIMPL(_RINTNBCA("no-avx2,no-bmi2",128),DEF ## O, A, N, 1)\
        _RINTNBIT_SMIMPL(_RINTNBCA("avx2,bmi2",256),AVX2 ## O, A, N, 8)\
        _RINTNBIT_SMIMPL(_RINTNBCA("avx512bw,avx512dq,avx512vl",512), \
            A512 ## O, A, N, 16)
    #define _RAND_INTNBIT_SEL(V,S) if(!S("cmov"))__builtin_cpu_init();\
        if(S("avx512dq")&&S("avx512vl")) (V = A512 ## V)(out,len,rng);\
        else if(S("avx2")&&S("bmi2")) (V = AVX2 ## V)(out,len,rng);\
        else (V = DEF ## V)(out,len,rng);
    #define RAND_INTN_NBIT_STREAM(NAME, ARGS, N) \
        _RAND_INTNBIT_VECIMPL(NAME,ARGS,N) static void SEL ## NAME ARGS;\
        void (*NAME) ARGS = SEL ## NAME ; _RINTNSIZE(SEL ## NAME ARGS) {\
            _RAND_INTNBIT_SEL(NAME, __builtin_cpu_supports) }
#elif defined(__aarch64__) && defined(__GNUC__)
    #define RAND_INTN_NBIT_STREAM(O,A,N) _RINTNBIT_SMIMPL(,REAL##O,A,N,2)\
                                         void (*O) A = REAL ## O ;
#else
    #define RAND_INTN_NBIT_STREAM(O,A,N) _RINTNBIT_SMIMPL(,REAL##O,A,N,1)\
                                         void (*O) A = REAL ## O ;
#endif

// NBIT_RNG_SIZE => rng bytes needed for SZ-int stream LEN-long and N bits in each
#define INTN_OF_NBIT_RNG_SIZE(SZ, LEN, N) (LEN * N)
```

The above code is written with portability fallbacks to work on MSVC as well (albeit at the significantly slower speed that all MSVC-generated C code runs at.)

Example usage:

```c
// Usage example. Feel free to rename these as desired:
//  - `uint32_t int32With4SetBits(uint32_t rng)` => get a random number with only 4 bits set from `rng`
//  - `void (*int32With4SetBitsStream)(uint32_t* out, size_t len, void* rng)` => stream `len` of
//       uint32_t to the `out` array, consuming `INTN_OF_NBIT_RNG_SIZE()` RNG bytes
RAND_INTN_NBIT(uint32_t, int32With4SetBits(uint32_t rng), 4)
RAND_INTN_NBIT_STREAM(int32With4SetBitsStream, (uint32_t* out, size_t len, void* rng), 4)
```

If your machine supports AVX512, then the AVX512 will look like the following and process 16 32-bit integers in 4 512-bit vectors simultaneously, which achieved 2.7 cycles per byte or 1200mb/s on my machine for the example setup of generating 32-bit integers with only 4 bits set each :

```
A512int32With4SetBitsStream:
        test    esi, 511
        jne     .L47
        mov     rcx, rdi
        lea     rdi, [rdi+rsi*4]
        cmp     rcx, rdi
        je      .L42
        mov     eax, 1
        mov     rsi, rdx
        vpxor   xmm9, xmm9, xmm9
        vpbroadcastd    zmm8, eax
        mov     eax, 31
        vpbroadcastd    zmm7, eax
.L39:
        vpxor   xmm13, xmm13, xmm13
        vmovdqa32       zmm14, zmm8
        vmovdqa32       zmm6, zmm8
        mov     edx, 4
        vmovdqa32       zmm5, zmm8
        vmovdqa32       zmm4, zmm8
        vmovdqa32       zmm12, zmm13
        xor     eax, eax
        vmovdqa32       zmm11, zmm13
        vmovdqa32       zmm10, zmm13
.L38:
        sub     eax, 5
        js      .L48
.L37:
        vpandd  zmm2, zmm10, zmm7
        vpandd  zmm1, zmm11, zmm7
        vpandd  zmm0, zmm12, zmm7
        vpsubd  zmm3, zmm9, zmm2
        vpsrld  zmm10, zmm10, 5
        vpandd  zmm15, zmm13, zmm7
        vpsrld  zmm11, zmm11, 5
        vpsrld  zmm12, zmm12, 5
        vpandd  zmm3, zmm3, zmm7
        vpsllvd zmm3, zmm4, zmm3
        vpsrlvd zmm4, zmm4, zmm2
        vpsubd  zmm2, zmm9, zmm1
        vpandd  zmm2, zmm2, zmm7
        vpsrld  zmm13, zmm13, 5
        vpsllvd zmm2, zmm5, zmm2
        vpsrlvd zmm5, zmm5, zmm1
        vpsubd  zmm1, zmm9, zmm0
        vpandd  zmm1, zmm1, zmm7
        vpord   zmm3, zmm3, zmm4
        vpsllvd zmm1, zmm6, zmm1
        vpsrlvd zmm6, zmm6, zmm0
        vpsubd  zmm0, zmm9, zmm15
        vpandd  zmm0, zmm0, zmm7
        vpsrlvd zmm15, zmm14, zmm15
        vpord   zmm2, zmm2, zmm5
        vpsllvd zmm0, zmm14, zmm0
        vpord   zmm1, zmm1, zmm6
        vpaddd  zmm4, zmm3, zmm8
        vpaddd  zmm5, zmm2, zmm8
        vpaddd  zmm6, zmm1, zmm8
        vpord   zmm4, zmm4, zmm3
        vpord   zmm0, zmm0, zmm15
        vpord   zmm5, zmm5, zmm2
        vpord   zmm6, zmm6, zmm1
        vpaddd  zmm14, zmm0, zmm8
        vpord   zmm14, zmm14, zmm0
        dec     edx
        jne     .L38
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rcx], zmm3
        add     rcx, 256
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rcx-192], zmm2
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rcx-128], zmm1
        vmovdqu32       ZMMWORD PTR [rcx-64], zmm0
        cmp     rdi, rcx
        jne     .L39
        vzeroupper
.L42:
        ret
```

Interestingly enough, Clang seems to autovectorize it to far better assembly output, taking advantage of `vprorvd` where GCC did not.

```
DEBA512int32With4SetBitsStream:
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB27_3
        xor     eax, eax
        # zmm0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        vpbroadcastd    zmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI27_0]
        vpternlogd      zmm1, zmm1, zmm1, 255
.LBB27_2:
        vmovdqu64       zmm2, zmmword ptr [rdx + 4*rax]
        vmovdqu64       zmm3, zmmword ptr [rdx + 4*rax + 64]
        vmovdqu64       zmm4, zmmword ptr [rdx + 4*rax + 128]
        vmovdqu64       zmm5, zmmword ptr [rdx + 4*rax + 192]
        vprorvd zmm6, zmm0, zmm2
        vprorvd zmm7, zmm0, zmm3
        vprorvd zmm8, zmm0, zmm4
        vprorvd zmm9, zmm0, zmm5
        vpsrld  zmm10, zmm5, 5
        vpsrld  zmm11, zmm4, 5
        vpsrld  zmm12, zmm3, 5
        vpsrld  zmm13, zmm2, 5
        vpsubd  zmm14, zmm6, zmm1
        vpord   zmm6, zmm14, zmm6
        vprorvd zmm6, zmm6, zmm13
        vpsubd  zmm13, zmm7, zmm1
        vpord   zmm7, zmm13, zmm7
        vprorvd zmm7, zmm7, zmm12
        vpsubd  zmm12, zmm8, zmm1
        vpord   zmm8, zmm12, zmm8
        vprorvd zmm8, zmm8, zmm11
        vpsubd  zmm11, zmm9, zmm1
        vpord   zmm9, zmm11, zmm9
        vprorvd zmm9, zmm9, zmm10
        vpsrld  zmm10, zmm5, 10
        vpsrld  zmm11, zmm4, 10
        vpsrld  zmm12, zmm3, 10
        vpsrld  zmm13, zmm2, 10
        vpsubd  zmm14, zmm6, zmm1
        vpord   zmm6, zmm14, zmm6
        vprorvd zmm6, zmm6, zmm13
        vpsubd  zmm13, zmm7, zmm1
        vpord   zmm7, zmm13, zmm7
        vprorvd zmm7, zmm7, zmm12
        vpsubd  zmm12, zmm8, zmm1
        vpord   zmm8, zmm12, zmm8
        vprorvd zmm8, zmm8, zmm11
        vpsubd  zmm11, zmm9, zmm1
        vpord   zmm9, zmm11, zmm9
        vprorvd zmm9, zmm9, zmm10
        vpsrld  zmm5, zmm5, 15
        vpsrld  zmm4, zmm4, 15
        vpsrld  zmm3, zmm3, 15
        vpsrld  zmm2, zmm2, 15
        vpsubd  zmm10, zmm6, zmm1
        vpord   zmm6, zmm10, zmm6
        vprorvd zmm2, zmm6, zmm2
        vpsubd  zmm6, zmm7, zmm1
        vpord   zmm6, zmm6, zmm7
        vprorvd zmm3, zmm6, zmm3
        vpsubd  zmm6, zmm8, zmm1
        vpord   zmm6, zmm6, zmm8
        vprorvd zmm4, zmm6, zmm4
        vpsubd  zmm6, zmm9, zmm1
        vpord   zmm6, zmm6, zmm9
        vprorvd zmm5, zmm6, zmm5
        vmovdqu64       zmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rax], zmm2
        vmovdqu64       zmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rax + 64], zmm3
        vmovdqu64       zmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rax + 128], zmm4
        vmovdqu64       zmmword ptr [rdi + 4*rax + 192], zmm5
        add     rax, 64
        cmp     rsi, rax
        jne     .LBB27_2
.LBB27_3:
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

On AARCH64 / ARM 64-bit, the following optimized NEON code is generated:

```
REALint32With4SetBitsStream:
        tst     x1, 511
        beq     .L2
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        adrp    x3, .LANCHOR0
        adrp    x1, .LC0
        mov     x29, sp
        adrp    x0, .LC1
        add     x3, x3, :lo12:.LANCHOR0
        add     x1, x1, :lo12:.LC0
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC1
        mov     w2, 642
        bl      __assert_fail
.L2:
        movi    v16.4s, 0x1
        add     x1, x0, x1, lsl 2
        movi    v5.4s, 0x1f
.L3:
        cmp     x0, x1
        beq     .L12
        movi    v0.4s, 0x1
        mov     w4, 4
        movi    v4.4s, 0
        mov     w3, 0
        mov     v3.16b, v0.16b
        mov     v6.16b, v4.16b
.L5:
        subs    w3, w3, #5
        bpl     .L4
        ldp     q6, q4, [x2]
        add     x2, x2, 32
        mov     w3, 32
.L4:
        and     v7.16b, v6.16b, v5.16b
        subs    w4, w4, #1
        and     v1.16b, v4.16b, v5.16b
        ushr    v6.4s, v6.4s, 5
        ushr    v4.4s, v4.4s, 5
        neg     v7.4s, v7.4s
        and     v2.16b, v7.16b, v5.16b
        sshl    v2.4s, v3.4s, v2.4s
        ushl    v3.4s, v3.4s, v7.4s
        orr     v2.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b
        neg     v3.4s, v1.4s
        and     v1.16b, v3.16b, v5.16b
        sshl    v1.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s
        ushl    v0.4s, v0.4s, v3.4s
        add     v3.4s, v2.4s, v16.4s
        orr     v1.16b, v1.16b, v0.16b
        orr     v3.16b, v3.16b, v2.16b
        add     v0.4s, v1.4s, v16.4s
        orr     v0.16b, v0.16b, v1.16b
        bne     .L5
        stp     q2, q1, [x0]
        add     x0, x0, 32
        b       .L3
.L12:
        ret
```

### Explanation: add-or

The basic building block of our algorithm will be the little-used *add-or*: `(a + b) | a | b`.

The neat thing about *add-or* is that, when `a` is a power of two, the bit count of b always increments by 1 unless integer overflow (e.x. past 2 to the power of 32 minus 1 for uint32_t):

```
a := 0b101101
b := 0b000100
a + b := 0b110001
addOr := (a + b) | a | b
addOr := 0b111101
```

Essentially, one can imagine the *addOr* operation as using the carry propagation properties of addition to search the integer for the first free zero slot where it can be held, then set this slot (addition), then set all the slots previously set (bitwise or).

### Explanation: handling the carry

OK, so our picture is coming together with add-or. Now, here's the simplest demo of the concept:

```c
uint32_t addOneBitTo(uint32_t to, unsigned pos) {
    uint32_t sum = to + (UINT32_C(1) << (pos & 31));
    uint32_t carry = sum < to; // detect overflow into 33rd bit
    sum += carry;
    uint32_t addOr = sum | to;
    return addOr;
}
```

This `addOneBitTo` method guarantees that the number of set bits in `to` will increment by 1 UNLESS `to` has all bits set (is `-1`), of course!

### Explanation: rotations

Adding the carry back to the sum carries a non-trivial dependency that restricts out-of-order execution to the unyielding critical path, so let's do better. Enter rotate.

Instead of checking for overflow, we can rotate the source bits and the add bit right so that the add bit becomes 1 and we are simply bitwise-oring `x + 1` against `x`:

```c
#define ROTATE32R(x,n) (x>>(n&31)) | (x<<(32-(n&31)))
#define ROTATE32L(x,n) (x<<(n&31)) | (x>>(32-(n&31)))

// gives THE SAME output as the previous `addOneBitTo`
uint32_t addOneBitTo(uint32_t to, unsigned pos) {
    to = ROTATE32R(to, pos);
    uint32_t sum = to + (UINT32_C(1) << 0); // now the new pos is 0
    // no carry(!!!)
    uint32_t addOr = sum | to;
    addOr = ROTATE32L(addOr, pos); // restore the rotation
    return addOr;
}
```

Because this is a RNG and we do not care about the output, just that it is random and uniformly distributed, we can remove the second rotate to produce the following neat building block. This is called repeatedly for random positions until the number of desired set bits is reached.

```c
#define ROTATE32R(x,n) (x>>(n&31)) | (x<<(32-(n&31)))

uint32_t randomAddBitTo(uint32_t to, unsigned pos) {
    to |= 1 + to;
    return ROTATE32R(to, pos);
}
```

That's all the explanation I have. I found nothing further of interest than this.